# Specify all child closed generic types using attributes in protobuf

Tags: generics, protobuf-net

I use protobuf-net 2.4 and have next class hierarchy:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class BaseStub
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class GenericStub<T1> : BaseStub
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T1 Value1 { get; set; }
}
```

and I know all possible types that will be used as T1 (for example only double). I can register this types in runtime, like this:

```
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
var baseType = model.Add(typeof(BaseStub), true);
model.Add(typeof(GenericStub<double>), true);
baseType.AddSubType(100, typeof(GenericStub<double>)
```

But can I do same using attributes? I try using ProtoInclude, but receive null reference errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(GenericStub<double>))]
public class BaseStub {...}
```

should work, for example - this then works for me:

```cs
BaseStub obj = new GenericStub<double> { Text = "abc", Value1 = 123.45 };
var clone = (GenericStub<double>)Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
Console.WriteLine($"{clone.Text}, {clone.Value1}");
```

If you're seeing NREs - a full repro would help.

Comment: You are right, this is work. I set ProtoInclude on generic type, in this case it throw exception.